# Copy file found in Script task to folder SSIS

Tags: ssis

i am new to coding and know a bit about ssis, i am able to help myself but i am stuck - i wanted to copy the latest .gz file from a folder to my own folder daily with a ssis script task, i was able to identify the lastest file with the script but i am getting stuck where said file needs to copy

here is is my script:

```
public void Main()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here

        var directory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::VarFolderPath"].Value.ToString());

        System.IO.FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("DailyReport-*.gz");
        DateTime lastModified = DateTime.MinValue;

        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (file.LastWriteTime > lastModified)
            {
                lastModified = file.LastWriteTime;
                Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value = file.ToString();
            }
        }

       // MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value.ToString());



    }
}
```

}

which works in identifying the file which i run within a Foreach loop container, but when i add a file system task, it does not copy the right file

i have variables saved for the copy 
User:DestinationFolder as Destination Connection
User:SourceFolder as Source Connection
with copy file as the operation

in my User:SourceFolder variable my value is saved as the exact file name i tested with originally, but it changed the next time the source folder was updated, and now the copy task keeps copying the same file

the file has basically the same name everytime it update, except for the end, for example

- DailyReport-20180725050247.gz at 6:00 in the morning
  and then
- DailyReport-20180725080801.gz at 8:00 the same morning

I want to copy the second one or whichever one updates later in the day

my variables:

- SourceFolder - X:\FTP\In\DailyReport-20180725050247.gz
- DestinationFolder - X:\MIS_AUTO\Lizl\Test
- VarFolderPath - X:\FTP\In
- VarFileName -

hope this makes sense

Comment: Does your package do anything else? If not, just write this in Powershell

Answer (score 0):

I did a try to re-pro your issue with a `Script Task` and `File System Task`.
The only thing that needs to be changed here is what actually passing through `User::VarFileName`. For a `File System Task` if you are choosing as variable for the `Source Connection -> IsSourcePathVariable` then you would need to pass the full file path information.

So, in script task you would need this -

```
Dts.Variables["User::VarFileName"].Value = file.FullName.ToString();
```

[image]